# Nifi AmqpConsumer get amqp$headers attribute

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-nifi, amqp

**AmqpConsumer** fetch the amqp data from given queue and put the flow.

Amqp data header value set in ***amqp$headers*** attributes.

So I tried to get this attribute by updateAttribute processor and using referance, but it was given an error.

[image]

The data like as above. But I can not reach as below by **updateAttribute**.

[image]

> How can set the **amqp$headers** in flow to **header** attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for referencing attributes is wrong, generally it would be ${amqp$headers}, but in your case, since you have a '$' in the attribute name, you reference it like ${'amqp$headers'}.

[image: It should look like this]

Comment: Thank you @Ryna , your aproach was solve my problem.